# fopen()/file_get_contents not working on the real server

Tags: php, image

I've developed a web site, and for some reasons i need to open the image from the disk. on my local config it is ok, working fine.. but deploying it to the real server, it seems not too be working. I get no errors but images open as empty. What should I do?

Comment: If normal Unix filesystem permissions are in order, check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `dmesg(1)` output to see if a  [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/) has denied access to the file.

Comment: `What should I do?` - Post your code. Give more details.

Comment: No way to answer this, voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that it is one of two things:

1. Permissions
2. Absolute paths were used instead of relative ones (e.g "C:\wwwroot\images\etc\image1.jpg" rather than something similar to "images/etc/image1.jpg"

Investigate some more.

Comment: Usually its the other way round on #2 - ie. someone is trying to use a relative path or they think that `/` is the path to the document root on the server.

Comment: Yeah I agree, that can be the case too, but I typically either omit the / or start with ./

Comment: yeah i always translate to the absolute path like `realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../)` to go up a directory or what have you. Using realtive paths for a actual operation tends to be asking for trouble in my experience :-)

Comment: totally that's the best way I've found to do it too, shame it's not just up on the PHP site somewhere saying "Do it this way, it works"

Comment: Got error_reportin(E_ALL).. it said  Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/sites/####/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Well there you go, permission denied :)